# Changing one element in a Matlab table is changing another element

Tags: matlab, matlab-table

I'm trying to edit a matlab table. It has a number of objects in it, each with multiple properties, one named `name` and one named `onset`.  When I edit the former, it is, for some reason, changing the latter, and I can't work out why.

This is a script that I have run (many times) on a Mac with no issue, and am now trying to run on a PC, and it is behaving completely differently.

```
>> tbl{1,2}.onset

ans =

   40.7700
   76.6800
  109.7550
  142.8300
  178.8750
  214.7850

>> tbl{1,2}.name='audword';
>> tbl{1,2}.onset

ans =

   40.7700
```

The above code is copied as-is from the Matlab console. Using Matlab 2021a, if it matters.